# Let user start working with app before loading fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a heavy **Timeline** fragment inside main activity.

If I insert fragment in XML, the application shows a white screen until the fragment is loaded completely and then entire application becomes visible. In this case I have following code in main activity XML:

```
<fragment android:name="com.example.Myapp.Timeline"
       android:id="@+id/timelinefragment"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />
```

If I load fragment dynamically **onWindowFocusChanged**  of main activity (is right place?), the main activity screen and buttons becomes visible as soon as application starts, but user can not start using app until the Timeline fragment becomes complete. In this case I have following code in main activity:

```
 @Override
   public void  onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
        super.onStart();

          FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
          FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
          fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.timelineHolder, timeline);
          fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }
```

In both case the application is unusable until the fragment is loading.How can I generate Fragment in background while user has started using other parts of application?

Comment: Maybe a better question would be what is your Timeline fragment doing that causes the application to hang? Are you properly doing long running tasks asynchronously?

Comment: my Timeline is formed of thousands layouts with different sizes which come from database. This is my exact question that "how should I generate them asynchronously"?

Comment: Thousands of layouts with different sizes - sounds like your problem is this. Not sure what to tell you without seeing your code

Comment: my Timeline contains 20*365 LinearLayouts with different heights according to the events in every day. I inflate a simple xml in a loop and set height for each one.

Comment: That is definitely an unreasonable amount of layouts. Convert your timeline to be some sort of view that uses recycling and only shows what views are on screen.

Comment: on top of what @egfconnor said, I would like to add. `onWindowFocusChanged` is not the right place. The right place is `onCreate(Bundle)` and you cannot call `super.onStart();`  inside `onWindowFocusChanged`